# How can I fix "Unresolved reference: java" in Spring Boot Kotlin project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have created Spring Boot project with

- SDK 11. Java Version 11.0.3
- Kotlin as language
- Gradle

I'm following this Tutorial:
https://scotch.io/@grahamcox82/how-to-build-a-simple-rest-api-with-kotlin-and-spring-boot

I'm trying to

```
import java.time.Instant
```

in my Kotlin data class

And have an error

> Unresolved reference: java

**build.gradle.kts file:**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.smight"
version = "0.0.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Maybe I should install java library? How can I check this?
Can anyone help please?

Comment: you should edit your question to add the code you are trying to execute so that we can understand better what you are talking about. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that JDK was not correct found from IntelliJ

**I solved the problem so:**

1. File -> Project Structure -> SDKs -> "+"
2. Find the path to your SDK where it is installed
3. New Project
4. Copy/Paste
5. Rebuild

Answer (score 3):

According to some research, this error can appear in this conditions :

- You created a Kotlin2Js project instead of Kotlin JVM ([source](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-unresolved-reference-java/6734/3)), try to recreate your project by selecting the right project type

or

- You are using a Kotlin version that does not support JDK 11 ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/6dsmon/unresolved_reference_for_all_classes_from_the/)), install JDK 8 instead and reconfigure your JAVA_HOME environment variable

It may as well be an error in your `build.gradle` file, copy/paste it in your question if the solutions above doesn't work

Comment: I've created with Spring Initializr a new Spring Boot Project with Project SDK 11 (java version 11.0.3). And then I've chosen Java Version 11. I have the latest Kotlin Version. Thank you for the antwort

Answer (score 1):

To get a more specific error you should first clean the autogenerated files

```
$ ./gradlew clean
```

---

In a modularized Spring project using Kotlin DSL the `unresolved reference` error could occur because the submodules are bootable.

### build.gradle.kts (Project)

```
...

subprojects {

    ...

    tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
        enabled = false
    }

    tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
        enabled = true
    }

}
```

GL